# Extract value from jQuery and pass into $_GET or a php variable

Tags: jquery, get

I'm new to jQuery (or all things javascript, really) but know my way around php and basic programming - sorry if my question sounds utterly stupid, trying my best to learn.

I'm using a seat selection jQuery script outlined on [TechBrij](http://techbrij.com/780/seat-reservation-with-jquery)

This is the part of the code that selects the seat (from a layout of airplane/bus seats)

```
$('.' + settings.seatCss).click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass(settings.selectedSeatCss)){
        alert('This seat is already reserved');
    } else{
        $(this).toggleClass(settings.selectingSeatCss);
    }
});
$('#btnShowNew').click(function () {
    var str = [], item;
    $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
        item = $(this).attr('title');
        str.push(item);
    });
    alert(str.join(','));
})
```

The selected Seat(s) are shown in an alert window on a click of a button & I want exactly that value.

I now want to pass the selected seat number into `$_GET` (or just into a php variable which I can then use as a `$_GET` value and just continue with it in PHP). If I understand it right I somehow need to grab the variable "str"? How would I do that?

Also, is there a way to limit the script to only allow ONE selected seat at a time? Right now it will only give an alert if I click on an already booked seat, I can select as many seats as I like, toggle them selected/unselected and such. Just setting it up that click on a seat set to "selectingSeatCss" will result in an alert would also stop me from unselecting it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of your question probably deserves its own question, but as for the main question:

If you are trying to pass the JavaScript variabble into a PHP script, you need to use ajax:

```
var seats = str.join(',');
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/the/script/url.php?seats=' + seats,
    success: function (response) {
         // do something with response
    }
});
```

You probably want to read more about jQuery's `$.ajax` here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Although, it really might make more sense to just do something with the `seats` value using JavaScript on the page, depending on what you are trying to do. If you want to save it to a database, you will probably want to send it to your PHP script.

**UPDATE**

To just put the value in a form, and submit the form, create a regular HTML form (you can put `display: none` in the css to hide it) and then:

```
var seats = str.join(',');
$('#formId input[name=seats]').val(seats).submit();
```

In this example, the form might look like this:

```
<form id="formId" action="/path/to/script.php" method="post">
    <input name="seats" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then the value will be available to the recieving script in `$_POST['seats']`

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply and the link to "further reading" :)

How would I go about to "just" extract the seats value into a php variable (not via GET) ? Not sure yet which way I want to go with this (not an actual project, just playing around with it)

Comment: Once the JavaScript is being executed, it is in the user's browser. PHP is already out of the picture at that point (since it is server-side). So you can't pass a variable to the PHP. You could pass it to another PHP script via `$.ajax` however.

Comment: Yes, you can send the value to a PHP script located at the `url` attribute, and then the script you sent it to can save the value in a database, and return a response, which you can then display to the user via JavaScript.

Comment: Could I leave the response out completely? Because all I basically need is: click the submit button which will then take the user to the page from the url attribute where the value (hidden) gets entered into a form (via POST), other fields in the form are filled out and a further submit will enter it into the database (all php from then on I guess as I already have that value) ?

Comment: Ok, this is the syntax newbie question you guys probably hate ... trying it anyway:
So if I want to trigger this on click (like the current alert window, same button) would I just replace the ` alert(str.join(','));` with the above code or do I need to make this a completely different function?

Thanks again for your help and patience with a newbie

Comment: You can just put whatever code you want into the `.click` function. The reason to create another function would be to make your code more manageable for yourself. If you want to do actually send the user to another page where their input is processed, you don't want to use the `$.ajax` function, which is for sending HTTP requests in the background. You could use jQuery to input `seats` into a hidden form, and then call `submit()` on the form.

Comment: Argh, I'm one step away from paying someone $20 to create this piece of code for me so I can just learn from the finished product. Seems like I need to read up a LOT more on this to actually grasp how to achieve what I want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @handofaten Thanks for the update to your answer about the hidden form - last idiot question as my brain is now utterly mush: where in my above script snippit would I actually put this (not the form, the javascript) ?